# Variant on the Subset Sum problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I was working through the [subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) problem and came across what looks like a general rule, but I can't prove that it's always the case.

I hope I explain this clearly...

If I have a set of numbers where no sum of a subset is equal to a sum of any other subset, I'm reasoning that any possible subset's sum would only have one unique subset that sums to it. Is that always the case? Or, is it possible that a target sum would have more than one subset that sums to it?

Comment: "If I have a set of numbers where no sum of a subset is equal to a sum of any other subset, I'm reasoning that any possible subset's sum would only have one unique subset that sums to it" -- that seems to be simply stating the same property in two slightly different ways. Did you mean to specify that "any other subset" should be _disjoint from_ the first one?

Comment: Thanks, yes, I'm wondering if I am actually restating the problem or is there something I'm missing. The subsets don't have to be disjoint.